# Time complexity for 2 nested loops

Tags: c++, algorithm

If I'm taking input through 2 nested For-loops  like this

```
cin>>x;

for(i=0;i<x;i++)
{
   cin>>y;

for(j=0;j<y;j++)

}
```

The complexity of the Outer loop is O(X)
but I'm confused about the Time complexity of the inner loop as the Y is variable.

Comment: It's `O(xY)`, where `Y` is the maximum `y` that is input.

Comment: The time complexity of the inner loop is nothing under any non-zero optimization level, because the compiler will remove the whole thing as a no-op.

Comment: The complexity is `O(sum(y))` - linear in the sum of inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of the outer loop is not `O(x)`, because the time it takes to run the outer loop depends on the value of y entered.

Let's say we have a sequence `y1,y2,...,yn` of inputs for y. Then the first loop would take `y1` operations and the second iteration would take `y2` operations and so on for each of the `x` iterations.

Now let `Y` be the max of this sequence of inputs, then each iteration of the outer loop would take at most `Y` operations. So we have that for `x` iterations each taking at most `Y` operations we get O(xY).

It is possible to specify further to a possibly smaller class of functions but it's important to remember that if `f < g` then `O(f)` is contained in `O(g)`. And that when we say a function is `O(f)` we just mean it is inside the class `O(f)`.

Considering in this case the input is not determined using the max would be a worst case scenario.

Also it would be more accurate if the input was outside all the loops as input isn't a constant operation most of the time. (This is trivial though, just have the y be input from a file or something and then use that to make an array.)